# How is mercury produced in industry?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Mercury is the only metal that exists in a liquid state at room temperature.

- In which form is mercury extracted from its ore?
- If it produced as a solid, how and when is it turned into a liquid?

Comment: There are many solid compounds that include mercury as one of their constituents. But, pure mercury at room temperature is a liquid as you point out.

Comment: tell me ik at room temperature it is liquid tell me in which state we get it from its ore.... that's my question

Comment: The classic way is to roast the ore, with the mercury coming off as a vapor that is readily condensed. Note that vaporized mercury is easily taken up by humans and damages the central nervous system.

Comment: I'll point out that most Hg now recovered in the US is as a byproduct to prevent pollution rather than being mined for the Hg itself.  https://archive.epa.gov/mercury/archive/web/pdf/byproductmercuryproductioninmodernpreciousmetalsminesinnevada.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly, mercury $\ce{Hg}$ is separated from its ore $\ce{HgS}$, known as cinnabar. The process used is roasting; this entails heating the raw material in oxygen.

$$\ce{HgS(l) + O2(g) ->[700-800\ ^\circ \mathrm{C}] Hg(g)  + SO2(g)}$$

Mercury is extracted here in the *gaseous* state. Note that the product is elemental mercury, not an oxide. This is because the oxides decompose at or below $500\ ^\circ \mathrm{C}$: $$\ce{Hg2O -> HgO + Hg,\\ HgO -> Hg + O2}.$$

The mercury vapor is then purified in multiple steps which depend on the required degree of purity. Usually the gaseous mercury is first cleansed from dust, then condensed (bp $356.6\ ^\circ \mathrm{C}$). At this stage, an $80\%$ yield is observed.

The condensed mass is filtered further, washed with bases and acids, and destilled. For ultrapure mercury (less than $10^{-6}\%$ of impurities), electrochemical refinement using mercury electrodes follows.

---

Hergi Karik, Kalle Truus. ($2003$). *Elementide keemia*. (pp 331$-$332, 334)

Comment: it means cinnabar exist in liquid state so how it is extracted from earth

Comment: @Utsavpandey No, cinnabar is a solid ore at standard conditions. The states are written in accordance with the reaction; the sulfide simply melts before $700-800\ ^\circ \mathrm{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Mercury is extracted from its ore, cinnabar($\ce{HgS}$). According to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)):

> Mercury is extracted by **heating cinnabar in a current of air and
>   condensing the vapor**. The equation for this extraction is
>
> $$\ce{HgS + O2 → Hg + SO2}$$
>
> In 2005, China was the top producer of mercury with almost two-thirds
>   global share followed by Kyrgyzstan. Several other countries are
>   believed to have unrecorded production of mercury **from
>   copper electrowinning processes and by recovery from effluents.**